# Sahi OS patch for IE11

Tags: patch, internet-explorer-11, sahi

Does anyone know how to patch Sahi OS to support IE 11.
I've add a check in the concat.js to detect IE 11 but still can't get _setvalue to works .

I know the Pro version support IE 11 but there's no OS version 5.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe there is a new OS version released!

Comment: Update to v5 but still have problem with IE11 using `_assertContainsText($VerTest, _div("WhatsNewDIV"));`. Sahi is timing out - FF is OK -

Comment: Fails when trying to navigate from     http://sahi.example.com/_s_/dyn/Driver_initialized?browserType=ie      but works OK if on correct server.

Comment: you can report the bug to the sahi team. They will resolve it soon.